# Inconsistent public-profile-url formats

Tags: url, linkedin-api

When using the LinkedIn API's people-search endpoint, I am getting inconsistent URL formats for the profiles returned. I performed a search yesterday, specifying a first and last name and requesting the public-profile-url, and all of the results had public profile URLs in the format:

https://www.linkedin.com/in/***

I performed the same search today and received the same profiles, but their public profile URLs were now in the format:

https://www.linkedin.com/pub/***

I know they're the same profiles because when I attempt to navigate to the pub URL in a browser it redirects me to the /in/ url. It was my understanding that the /pub/ format had been discontinued, and that all profiles are now created with the /in/ public profile url format.

Why then are public-profile-urls being returned in /pub/ format at seemingly random times? This is causing issues for my application as its resulting in duplicate accounts in my db.

Comment: is `***` a valid identifier? Is it the same between accounts?  If a user updated their name would it change?

Comment: @dm03514 it is the same between URL formats, its just slightly reformatted for /in/ URLs, i.e. the letters are rearranged. Updating a name would not change the URL, but users do have the option of changing their public profile url to have a custom name following the /in/, like /in/tebow. **I've also seen the people-search endpoint return the /pub/ url format of a profile that has updated its /in/ format to be a custom name, which in my mind is clearly incorrect behavior**

Comment: _"This is causing issues for my application as its resulting in duplicate accounts in my db"_ - doesn't their search endpoint offer a better user identifier than just a profile URL ...?

Comment: @CBroe we actually use the public-profile-url field as the uid because the LinkedIn get-profile API exposes more users when querying with a public-profile-url than with their "id" field. We are looking into using the "id" field as a deduper, but its a non-trivial change to our stack

Comment: So you deliberately chose a value that, by my guess, is not documented as being permanent/unchangeable anywhere, instead of the designated user identifier ...? One might call that "clearly incorrect behavior," ha ha :)

Comment: @CBroe We have processes in place to handle updates to URLs, which have worked perfectly. The added complexity of having those processes is the price we pay for access to more profile data. The only issue is when the API starts returning incorrect values for a given profile field. Which could just as easily happen for the id field, or any other field for that matter. There's only so much you can do to insulate yourself against an API that returns incorrect, indeterministic data

Comment: _"[...] the price we pay for access to more profile data"_ - maybe access is limited for good reasons? _"The only issue is when the API starts returning incorrect values for a given profile field"_ - the value you get takes you to the correct location when you call it in a browser, so it is hardly an "incorrect value." But your _use_ of it is incorrect.